# How do you verify a good ground connection when using EMT conduit as the ground?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding, conduit, nec

When using metallic conduit as the ground wire, how do you confirm that the conduit provides a solid end-to-end connection?

If using an ohm meter, how would you set it up and how many ohms are acceptable?

Do inspectors check these things somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install it properly with clean metal-metal contact.

- Don't just hand-spin the conduit nuts, get a screwdriver and hammer and tighten them by putting the screwdriver on the serrations made for that purpose and tapping.
- On the conduit compression fittings, tighten those with a wrench.
- On setscrew fittings, tighten the setscrews with a tool.

Since metallic conduit has massively more conductivity than any size of ground wire appropriate for any circuit that will fit inside it, I don't think an ohmmeter measurement would be constructive.

Comment: Good point on spinning the conduit nut with screwdriver+hammer.  I didn't realize thats what the nut edges were for!

Comment: I asked a similar [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/215262/how-is-ground-path-formed-between-emt-and-painted-metal-boxes-is-the-paint-cond/216424#216424)  adding that the EMT is connected to a *painted* box.  My interpretation of the answers was that doing that reliably requires some skill, training and experience and needs to be done purposefully.

Comment: I run a seperate ground wire, I have seen many times where over time the condulet becomes separated and or the joints oxidize and the resistance goes up. This can become a problem with electronic controls.